# Can github actions automatically open web pages?

Tags: github-actions

My requirement is to automatically open a web page `every 5 hours` (for example: `www.xxx.com`, I don't need to see the content of this page, just open it). The page takes `3 minutes` to load, and then just close the page.

Can I use Github Actions to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Are you asking whether this is _technically_ possible or are you looking for an answer based on GitHub's terms of service?

Comment: Hello, I was actually asking if this is technically feasible (or if there are already samples of similar requirements). 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this technically possible. GitHub Actions has the `on.schedule` [event](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) which allows you to essentially set up a cron schedule for execution of your workflow. Your cron schedule for running the workflow every 5 hours would be something like `0 0/5 * * *` (see [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_0/5_*_*_*)).

If you just want to open the webpage for 3 minutes, your workflow run step could use the `&&` chaining the URL-opening command (`xdg-open www.example.com` can be used to open a URL) with a `sleep 360`. I leave the actual composition of the workflow file as an exercise to the reader .

Comment: Could you please post an answer to the question?